# preposition for "shared"

Tags: prepositions

Consider an application called "OpenTasks". "OpenTasks" has a feature to share a task with another person.

Now Alice shares a task with Bob.

What's the right preposition in the following expression?

**The task has been shared by Alice with Bob *???* OpenTasks.**

Or in short:

**The task has been shared *???* OpenTasks.**

I've tried "with" and "from" but neither of them sound quite right to me.

Comment: shared tasks use 'and'

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I need a preposition to express that I (or Alice) was using a specific application (called "OpenTasks") when I (or Alice) shared the task with Bob. How does 'and' fit in here?

Comment: sharing involves equality, so i chose 'and' instead of 'with' which still gives Alice controlling rights over the task, and thus is not true 'sharing'. 'with' works however.

Comment: The safest choice is *using*, by my lights, but *with* works, too.

Comment: In this case "share" means the "sent to" feature found on mobile devices. So Alice and Bod don't have the same instance of the task, instead Bob gets a copy. Not sure if that still counts as "true sharing". It's "share" like in "sharing an information" not like in "sharing an object".

Comment: @JonMarkPerry OP is asking about what to use with adding "OpenTasks" as the tool/location for sharing the task. Also, your "and' suggestion doesn't make sense otherwise. Please provide an example

Comment: Using OpenTask, this task has been shared by Alice and Bob. i think i misread the question though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete this there are a few words you can use:

All of the following, and probably a few more, would work:

> The task has been shared by Alice with Bob **with** OpenTasks.
>
> The task has been shared by Alice with Bob **using** OpenTasks.
>
> The task has been shared by Alice with Bob **via** OpenTasks.
>
> The task has been shared by Alice with Bob **through** OpenTasks.

The same words will work in the second, shorter, form.

Answer (score 1):

Typically we **share** that which can be shared...

a sandwich

good news

a seat

and we share it **with** someone else.

The question is whether **task** is an appropriate object for the verb **share**. I'm not sure what it would mean to share a task with someone.  Invite them to help you with it?

If we use some vehicle or device to share something with another person, the preposition would be **through** or **by** or **over** or **via**, depending on the vehicle.

> I shared the news with her by phone.
>
> They shared the news of the early dismissal over the intercom.
>
> They shared the news of his departure through an inter-office mailing.
>
> Marge shared the task with Homer via OpenTasks.

Comment: ok, if it matters, we share a document/text describing the task rather than the task as such. I've considered "via" but it sounded more like a preposition for the transport mechanism, i.e. "shared via email/SMS/…"

Comment: I'd say *A task [something or other] is shared via OpenTasks*. It is hard to know what name to give the something-or-other without first knowing what is supposed to be done with it by the recipient/person with whom it is shared.  Nothing wrong with **via** to describe a conduit.  But if OpenTasks also provides a collaboration workspace, then it is more than a conduit.

Answer (score 0):

*In*.

Things are done "inside" computer programs when you use their functions.

> The task has been shared by Alice with Bob **in** OpenTasks.